# How to setup SpiderOak backups by copying files offline

Tags: backup

I have a machine setup with a SpiderOak backup running about 140GB of data.

I would like to sync that data to my netbook.

The only way of doing this as far as I can see is creating a SO backup for the netbook then syncing the two devices.

The drawback of this is that I'm going to use 140GB of download, which in New Zealand is not cheap.

Is there any way I can copy the data offline via external hdd to the netbook, then setup a sync without having to download all the data over the net?

Many thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone else comes across this while looking for the same problem, I fixed it in the end.

The key is to create a backup on the first machine. Then copy the data from the first to the second machine using an external hdd.

Setup the second machine as a second device in SO and setup a backup.

Once both machines are backed up, sync the folders you need to have identical. All done.

Note the filesystems on my two machines were identical. I am not sure how this would work with non-identical filesystems.